# 2d list in python getting error as "name 'Website' is not defined"

Tags: python

Got a reference code from a book but not getting desired output. getting error as "Wesbite" is not defined not able to find any solution of it.

```
siteData = [
    ['O\'Reilly Media', 'http://oreilly.com', 'h1', 'section#product-description'],
    ['Reuters', 'http://reuters.com', 'h1', 'div.StandardArticleBody_body_1gnLA'],
    ['Brookings', 'http://www.brookings.edu', 'h1', 'div.post-body'],
    ['New York Times', 'http://nytimes.com', 'h1', 'div.StoryBodyCompanionColumn div p']
]
websites = []
for row in siteData:
    websites.append(Website(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

Comment: You never define a class or function `Website`

Comment: There is no variable `Website`. Maybe, it is `siteData`

Comment: Lokks as if `Website` should be a class and `Website(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])` should create an instance of this class. You're missing some code here.

Answer (score 0):

`Website` is being referenced/called as a variable, function, or class, but it hasn't been defined, which is causing the `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write SiteData or Website is anything you haven't defined

Comment: This could be comment. See how others have already commented about this.